# Swift Cannot assign a value of type 'CGPath' to a value of type 'CGPath?'

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm attempting to round just the top left and bottom left corners of a `UITextField`. Here is the code I am using:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: locationText.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .TopLeft | .BottomLeft, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)).CGPath

    locationText.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

The line

```
maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: locationText.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .TopLeft | .BottomLeft, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)).CGPath
```

is producing the error

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'CGPath' to a value of type 'CGPath?'
```

This is confusing me since I've been able to set values to optionals no problem elsewhere in the code. Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using swift 2.0 with Xcode beta it is probably an error of the compiler that is trying to say to you that you should use an array to indicate the corners

```
maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)).CGPath
```